# How to convert an Option[String]to List [String]in Scala

Tags: scala

How to convert an `Option[String]` to a `List[String]`?

My `Option[String]` looks like this : `Some("value1,value2")`

i tried this but with no success

```
def convertOptionToList(a: Option[String]): List[String] = {

    return a.map(x => x.split(",").toList)

  }
```

At the end i want something like this : List("val1","val2","val3");

Comment: Yes it is, but what i want is List[String], not Option[List[String]]

Comment: Could you add a complete example? I can't quite figure out how you're passing `Some("value1","value2")` into an `Option[String]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove `.toList` where you have it, and add `.toList.flatten` at the end:

```
a.map(_.split(",")).toList.flatten
```

Alternatively, do `.toList` first, and then `.flatMap` instead of `.map`:

```
a.toList.flatMap(_.split(","))
```

But, if it really looks like `Some("value1","value2")`, then it is not an `Option[String]` to begin with. It is an `Option[(String, String)]`. A tuple inside the `Option` is a pair of strings. Do this in this case:

```
a.toList.flatMap { case (a,b) => Seq(a,b) }
```

(although, I don't think it makes much sense to be converting tuples to lists. tuples are better).

Comment: I'm using :  val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0). params.get("params") returns an Option[String] so that's why i need such conversion. I can also have Some("value1","value2","Value3", etc )

Comment: `a.toList.flatMap(_.split(","))` doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am doing this: `val a: Option[String] = Some("value1","value2")
 a.toList.flatMap(_.split(","))` but I get too many arguments for method `apply`

Comment: You are passing two strings to `Some`, should be one: `Some("value1,value2")`